# Typescript get children from parent ids

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to create a new array with children from my database result. I've tried something and actually it worked a bit but where am i missing, can you help me?

This is my data coming from database:

```json
[
    {
        "nodeId": "1",
        "label": "Applications"
    },
    {
        "nodeId": "2",
        "label": "Calendar",
        "parentId": "1"
    },
    {
        "nodeId": "3",
        "label": "Documents"
    },
    {
        "nodeId": "4",
        "label": "OSS",
        "parentId": "3"
    },
    {
        "nodeId": "5",
        "label": "MUI",
        "parentId": "3"
    },
    {
        "nodeId": "6",
        "label": "index.js",
        "parentId": "5"
    }
]
```

And this is what i want to convert the data coming from database to:

```json
[
    {
        "nodeId": "1",
        "label": "Applications",
        "children": [
            {
                "nodeId": "2",
                "label": "Calendar"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "nodeId": "3",
        "label": "Documents",
        "children": [
            {
                "nodeId": "4",
                "label": "OSS"
            },
            {
                "nodeId": "5",
                "label": "MUI",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "nodeId": "6",
                        "label": "index.js"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried this code below.

```
interface TreeData {
    nodeId: string;
    label: string;
    parentId?: string;
}

interface RealTreeData {
    nodeId: string;
    label: string;
    children?: RealTreeData[];
}

const treeData: TreeData[] = [
    {
        nodeId: '1',
        label: 'Applications'
    },
    {
        nodeId: '2',
        label: 'Calendar',
        parentId: '1'
    },
    {
        nodeId: '3',
        label: 'Documents'
    },
    {
        nodeId: '4',
        label: 'OSS',
        parentId: '3'
    },
    {
        nodeId: '5',
        label: 'MUI',
        parentId: '3'
    },
    {
        nodeId: '6',
        label: 'index.js',
        parentId: '5'
    }
];

function test(data: TreeData[]) {
    const realData: RealTreeData[] = [];
    const ignore: string[] = [];

    for (const treeData of data) {
        const children = data.filter(x => x.parentId === treeData.nodeId);

        if (children.length) {
            const childrenData = test(children);

            for (const child of childrenData) {
                ignore.push(child.nodeId);
            }

            realData.push({
                label: treeData.label,
                nodeId: treeData.nodeId,
                children: childrenData
            });
        } else {
            if (!ignore.includes(treeData.nodeId)) {
                realData.push({
                    label: treeData.label,
                    nodeId: treeData.nodeId
                });
            }
        }
    }

    return realData;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(test(treeData), undefined, 4));
```

And I got this output:

```json
[
    {
        "label": "Applications",
        "nodeId": "1",
        "children": [
            {
                "label": "Calendar",
                "nodeId": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "Documents",
        "nodeId": "3",
        "children": [
            {
                "label": "OSS",
                "nodeId": "4"
            },
            {
                "label": "MUI",
                "nodeId": "5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "MUI",
        "nodeId": "5",
        "children": [
            {
                "label": "index.js",
                "nodeId": "6"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: can you do it in your db query? It will generally be preferable performance-wise.

Comment: I am using MongoDB and mongoose. So how should i query?

Comment: i don't know mongoose very well, but you might use this: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mertcan Yüzer** *(from a discord server)* found a solution. Thanks!

```
function test(treeItems: TreeData[]): RealTreeData[] {
        const result: RealTreeData[] = [];

        for (const item of treeItems) {
            const newItem: RealTreeData = item;

            if (!newItem.parentId) {
                result.push(newItem);
            }

            const children = treeItems.filter(
                treeItem => treeItem.parentId === newItem.nodeId
            );

            if (children.length) {
                newItem.children = children;
            }

            delete newItem.parentId;
        }

        return result;
    }
```